# How to kill and stop uvicorn from respawning when running in the background (when started with nohup)

Tags: linux, daemon, nohup, uvicorn

I started a fastapi app and uvicorn in the background with `nohup` as

```
nohup uvicorn main:app &
```

and it seems it runs as root in the background and if I kill it, it will soon respawn using `kill -9 $(ps -efl | grep uvicorn | head -1 | awk '{print $4}')`. Is there any way to kill or stop it without rebooting the server?

Answer (score -1):

You can try these alternatives.

```bash
pkill uvicorn
```

or

```bash
killall uvicorn
```

And with `awk 'print $2'`

```bash
kill -9 $(ps -efl | grep uvicorn | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
```